# Tello Edu Drone With Python

Tags: python

I am using the code from " https://github.com/dji-sdk/Tello-Python " and I'm able to get a live footage using my phone BUT not on my PC. Followed the guide and after extracting the files and such, all I get is error

```
import tello

from tello_control_ui import TelloUI

def main():
    drone = tello.Tello('', 8889)
    vplayer = TelloUI(drone, "./img/")

    # start the Tkinter mainloop
    vplayer.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I got was: `No Module named Tello.`

Comment: Please post the full error stack. If the error occurs on the ``import`` line, chances are you are running the app from an env where tello is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you havent installed the package on your machine.

Try running `pip install tello` from your systems console

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new to this I thought I installed tello but it says Tello does not exist in my system

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: In windows open cmd and type in `pip install tello`

Comment: I'm currently using 64-bit and yes I have typed that command but it says it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tello and no matching distribution found for tello

Comment: Sorry i didnt check if that package was in pypi, its not.
Make shure the extracted files are in the Working Directory or in pythons lib folder